# RegisterAssemblyModule Creates Registrations - Still Getting ComponentNotRegisteredException

Tags: reflection, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have the following very simple ViewModel with interface:

```cs
public interface ITestViewModel
{
    string Tester { get; }
}

public class TestViewModel : ITestViewModel
{
    public string Tester
    {
        get { return "testing DI"; }
    }
}
```

I've then created this Autofac module:

```cs
public class TestModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(c => new TestViewModel()).As<ITestViewModel>();
    }
}
```

The ViewModel and this Module live in a separate DLL called TestPlugin.

From my main application, I am attempting to dynamically load the TestPlugin assembly, so that I can register its modules with the container as in the code below:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var plugins = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\plugins", "TestPlugin.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
foreach (var plugin in plugins)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(plugin);
    builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assembly);
}
var container = builder.Build();
var testResolve = container.Resolve<ITestViewModel>();
```

For some reason, although I can clearly see a component registration for service ITestViewModel (DelegateActivator of TestViewModel), I still receive the following exception on the Resolve call:

```
Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233088
Message=The requested service 'TestPlugin.ITestViewModel' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
Source=Autofac
StackTrace:
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context)
   at Test.App.<>c__DisplayClass5.<OnStartup>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
InnerException:
```

Would appreciate any help with why this is happening. My guess is that it has something to do with the Assembly.LoadFrom call, as if I try pulling the viewmodel/module into the main app then the registration seems to work properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the assembly into the current App domain. Take a look at [AppDomain.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36az8x58.aspx).